# How to get user data from a controller if the api contains bearer token?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am creating a method in controller that returns bunch of data. And some parameter depends on the authenticated user. So, How can I get the authenticated user data if, the request has Bearer token.
P.S applying middleware is not the option, since, same method can be accessible by unauthenticated request too.

In controller I used `Auth::guard('api')->user();` which return nothing. Since I am not using middleware. The Auth::guard('api')->user(); returns user data only if I use middleware.

Comment: What auth are you using? You may be able to access the user using `$request->user()` and check if that returns anything other than `null`

Comment: @LewisSmith $request->user() returns nothing unless I use  middleware('auth:api')  .

Comment: This might sound nuts, but could you have 2 routes in the router, one with and one without the auth guard both pointing at the same controller function and then use that?